# Why image doens't link with the right path?

Tags: html, css

Why I can't see my image even if I have the right link?

Code:

```
<img href="Layout-home.jpg" style="">
```

The path of the root is in a USB ("grafica"), and the enteire link is:

file:///E:/MIKY-BEN/grafica/Layout-home.jpg

"grafica" is the ROOT. (whith the index.html file inside).

Answer (score 3):

The attribute is `src`, not `href`. This error would have been picked up if you had used [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: Ok you're right, but, I can't still see the image.. why?

Comment: That's the only reason that is exposed by your question.

Comment: I have my stylsheet with uri "css/template.css", I have my <img> with the uri "img/isabellina-nel-ghiaccio.jpg". What's wrong with the image? The stylsheet it's loaded correctly, the image no..

Comment: @SashaChirico — Aside from being inconsistent with what you claimed the path was in the question: There is nothing obviously wrong with that.

Comment: yes I know and sorry for that, but I can't figured out why my image still not appear.. Maybe I need another question for this.. but if someone write here the solution it will be great too.

Comment: @SashaChirico — You haven't provided enough information to allow the new problem to be identified.

Comment: After I had corrected the 'href' with 'src' the image appear (with the broken image), but appear. 
So, I linked the image egual to the stylesheet (in fact, the stylesheet works) but the image no.. It's a simple static html site.. with a path with the "css" and another one with the path "img". But I need to maintain the images inside the USB, and maybe it's the permission?